# SQL COUNT Second ('mode') Argument showing in Notepad++'s tooltip thing

Tags: sql, notepad++

A new feature in Notepad++ is that if you write a function name and an open brace (`print_r(`) it will show you the arguments it is expecting. As I was creating an SQL query I noticed that when I type `SELECT COUNT(`, this appears:

```
int COUNT ( mixed var, [int mode = COUNT_NORMAL] )
```

I googled and couldn't find anything. Do you know what the second argument is, what effect it has on the query and what other options I can use besides COUNT_NORMAL?

Comment: Based on a Google search and results (for example http://docs.php.net/manual/da/function.count.php) it seems as though [notepad++] is giving you argument options for **PHP not SQL**

Comment: That's a prototype for PHP's count() ...

Comment: You're right, I even checked the PHP count thing but must've read it wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notepad++ thinks you're editing a `PHP` code (see http://php.fnlist.com/array/count). You'll have to switch Notepad++ to `SQL`.